# What does "pissy butt" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Miles, I swear you were the most bed-wettingest kid in Brooklyn. Matter fact, back then I used to get this trash paper every morning, just so we could line the top of your mattress with it in the evening.” Mr. Davis closed the paper, folded it in half. He shook his head. “And then your **pissy butt** would come waddling into our bedroom in the middle of the night smelling like two-hundred-year-old lemonade, talkin’ ’bout, I had an accident. An accident? I’ma tell you right now, son, be thankful for your mother, because if it were up to me, you would’ve been lying in the wet spot until it was a dry spot.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the kid had urine on his behind, because he had peed himself in bed.

pissy

```
adj.
Irritable; cranky.
adj.
Covered in piss.
adj.
Resembling or smelling like piss.
```

piss

noun

Definition of piss (Entry 2 of 2)

1 usually vulgar : urine

butt

noun (1)
\ ˈbət
\
Definition of butt

(Entry 1 of 6)

1 : buttocks

slipped and fell on his butt

Comment: Saying something-butt is a common insult among children 'whiney-butt' for instance.

Comment: It could be a play on words somewhat.